# How to prevent Typescript from loading `.d.ts` files from a directory?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm only using 1 client from `aws-sdk`. I noticed if I remove the `aws-sdk` import, `tsc` run time gets cut in half. When running `tsc --listFiles`, I noticed that TS is importing every `.d.ts` file in `node_modules/aws-sdk`.

I tried adding `node_modules` to `exclude` in `tsconfig.json`, but it didn't do anything.

Is it possible to prevent TS from importing any `.d.ts` files from `node_modules/aws-sdk`? Then, I can manually import the single file I need.

Comment: Try excluding `node_modules/aws-sdk/**/*.d.ts`. Per docs, exclude is applied before includes, so when you `import sdk from 'aws-sdk'`, you're overriding the exclude.